# Convert python list to array to perform a match

Tags: python, arrays, list, replace, matching

I would really appreciate some help.

I'm having problems with an output from pymining / itemmining which creates association rules from transaction baskets.
The output (rules) i'm getting is a list like this:

```
[(frozenset({'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}),
  frozenset({'X'}),
  55,
  0.8870967741935484),
 (frozenset({'U', 'Z', 'D'}),
  frozenset({'G', 'Q'}),
  55,
  0.5445544554455446),...]
```

which means if a customer has bought items `A B C D E` he is likely to buy next item X.. (this happens 55 times and has a confidence of .55)

I've tried converting my list to an array using replace functions:

```
rules2 = str(rules)
rules2 = rules2.replace('(frozenset({', '[')
```

but I don't think it's correct way to convert to a proper array?

I'm wanting to match the above list with a file of fresh transactions which looks like this:

```
array([['D', 'F', 'G'],
       ['A', 'B'], dtype=object)
```

So that if a customer has bought products 'D F G' I know what we should recommend next...

Many thanks who can help I'm really stuck! I tried to convert rules to dataframe but I get an error msg saying `'InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.'` when i try to query it

Comment: A+ for creativity in trying to convert list to array! But that is not at all how it works. `rules` is a list of tuples with four items in each tuple. Are you trying to extract the first two items of each one into a numpy array of arrays? The second array looks like a pandas index, is that right? Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but try this to get started: `rules2 = [[list(x[0]), list(x[1])] for x in rules]`

Comment: hi, thks for your help. I'm new ish to python :-)

Comment: hi, thks for your help. I'm new ish to python :-) we are almost there. do you know how i can find matches between the 2 arrays: array 1 is array([['A', 'B', 'C'],
       [['F'], ['G']], dtype=object) and array 2 is array([[['A', 'B', 'C'],
        ['X']],
       [['F'], ['G']], dtype=object)  so i want to find ['A', 'B', 'C'] in array 2 and return ['X'] ?? (big thank you)